# Maya script won't run in Maya 2022. `reload` is not defined

Tags: python, maya, python-2to3

Trying to run a script that works fine in maya 2018 but wont in 2022

```
import gw_anim_clip
reload(gw_anim_clip)
gw_anim_clip.anim_clip_ui()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: name 'reload' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined #
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a python2.7 to python3 problem. You can try to use ` from importlib import reload` if you are working with pyton3.

Comment: thanks where should i add that sorry inexperienced with python just trying to get my maya scripts to work?

Answer (score 1):

reload is not available in python 3.9 and maya 2022 already in 3.9. So you have to use importlib.reload to reload a module.

```
import importlib
import gw_anim_clip
importlib.reload(gw_anim_clip)
gw_anim_clip.anim_clip_ui()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maya 2022 use python 3.7 and you need to import *reload* first.

```
from imp import reload
import gw_anim_clip
reload(gw_anim_clip)
gw_anim_clip.anim_clip_ui()
```